# How do I reference the image file in my program appropriately without it causing an error?

Tags: java, image, file, runtime-error

[Here's my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmJ81.png)

The working directory for my program is printed at the bottom along with the error message, and on the left hand side of the screen my download png is located directly within my test project where the working directory is supposed to be. I have also tried using the direct file path of my download png within the getResource() method, but that didn't work either (I used double backslashes so that wasn't the issue).

```
package test;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import java.io.File;

public class Test{
    public Test() {
        System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
        ImageIcon download = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("download.png"));
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
        
    }

}
```

(Yes I know I didn't have to import Icon but I wanted to match what I had in the picture)

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Comment: I changed it to include my code as text

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was put the download.pgn file in the package where my class was located rather than the project that the absolute path was telling me to put it and the code worked. Hopefully this helps others who are having the same problem